# Bootstrap - How to hide contents in navbar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to hide the contents' titles inside navbar (because they're already showed in the page's body) and they can only be showed in the collapse button when scale down the screen. In other words, except the brand, there'll be no content in the navbar, and the content can only be showed in the navbar when scale down the screen and open the collapse button. I don't know any class that can hide contents. I tried to use hidden-... but it didn't work. Could you suggest me some ways?

Here are my codes:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
  <title>Module 3 Assignment</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-brand">
                <a href="module3-assignment.html" class="pull-left"><h1>Food, LLC</h1></a>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-nav" aria-expanded="false">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>

            <div id="collapse-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul id="#nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm">
                        <a href="#chicken"><br class="hidden-xs"/>Chicken</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm">
                        <a href="#beef"><br class="hidden-xs"/>Beef</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="hidden-md hidden-sm">
                        <a href="#sushi"><br class="hidden-xs" />Sushi</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
  </header>



  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have anything in your `style.css`? Works fine for me here: http://jsbin.com/rawunuqibo/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! But I can't find out how my css could have something to do with this effect. I do have some code in my css but it just to edit the color and text.

Comment: Er... Not sure! `:(`

Comment: Oh I just did it using "hidden" class. Thank you anyway! :)

Comment: Any particular reason why you have the class attribute set to "hidden-xs" in the <br> tag instead of in the <a> tag or in the <li> tag?